# Bootstrap modal not loading in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, safari

**Context:** I have a working modal on the page along with some links.

**Goal:** I would like to make the modal show when I click on the link right before the page redirects.

**Problem:** This code works on all the browsers I've tested on so far (even IE8), *EXCEPT* Safari #safariisthenewie. I have even tried to preventDefault and then manually redirect with `window.location.href = 'http://something.com'`. Somebody help me!

```
// HTML Markup
<a id="test" href="http://something.com">Click Me</a>
<!-- Some bootstrap modal markup here -->

// Javascript Code
$('#test').on('click', function() {
  // this works
  alert('hello');

  // this doesn't work in safari
  $('#loading-modal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  });
});
```

**Fun facts:**

- The modal shows up when I click on the stop button while the new page is loading
- The modal shows up when I add a breakpoint to the javascript handler and continue when it is triggered.

This is an example [js bin](https://jsbin.com/yuyinaleye/edit?html,js).

P.S. To make the demo work you have to click on the diagonal arrow thing in the output header to open the demo in a new tab, otherwise the link won't redirect.

Comment: In general, I think trying to show a modal as the next page is loading is a bad idea, because you don't really have control over whether the user actually sees the modal or how long they see it or anything like that. Instead of opening the link immediately, perhaps have a button to continue to the link in the modal, or use a timer to automatically continue to the next page after a few seconds.

Comment: @oxguy3 I agree. However, I do not have the luxury to make that decision easily. I could try the timer.

Comment: @Madness The script in my code is wrapped to a doc ready call. JS bin does that automatically by placing the javascript code to the bottom of the page. Either way it doesn't fix that problem.